# Query as table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

hi guys i need some help, how do you create this query in rails controller?

SELECT * FROM (SELECT id,amount,user_id FROM payments
WHERE user_id='10000' ORDER BY id DESC) WHERE rownum <=1;

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Which parts do you thin you could do in Rails if you pulled them out of the main query? what have you googled for to try to make the other parts work and why were the results unsatisfactory for you?

Answer (score 4):

This is way in rails

```
Payment.select('*').from(Payment.select('id,amount,user_id, row_number over () as rn').where("user_id= 10000").order('id DESC')).where('rn <= 1')
```

OR

```
Payment.find_by_sql('SELECT * FROM (SELECT id,amount,user_id FROM payments WHERE user_id='10000' ORDER BY id DESC) WHERE rownum <=1')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT id,amount,user_id FROM payments WHERE user_id='10000' ORDER BY id DESC) WHERE rownum <=1;"

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Comment: hi thx for giving and idea but how can i get the data from the query using that method? 

@value = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
render json: {:sql => @value} 

??